# org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException Various other error cases

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, backend

I'm having trouble programming because I'm experiencing this error.

```
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:798) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:237) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:975) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:959) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1354) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1343) ~[spring-boot-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
        at com.spring.board.Demo13Application.main(Demo13Application.java:10) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:50) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.2.3.jar:3.2.3]
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'fileService' defined in file [C:\Users\bakeo\git\imageuploadStudy\demo1-3\bin\main\com\spring\board\FileService.class]: Failed to instantiate [com.spring.board.FileService]: Constructor threw exception
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:318) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:306) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1355) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1192) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:562) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:325) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:254) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1443) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1353) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:907) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:785) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [com.spring.board.FileService]: Constructor threw exception
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:223) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:111) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:315) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        ... 38 common frames omitted
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
        at java.base/java.util.Objects.requireNonNull(Objects.java:209) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem.getPath(WindowsFileSystem.java:216) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Path.of(Path.java:147) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:69) ~[na:na]
        at com.spring.board.FileService.<init>(FileService.java:29) ~[main/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:210) ~[spring-beans-6.1.4.jar:6.1.4]
        ... 40 common frames omitted
```

this is my Code

FileController.java

```
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.springframework.http.MediaType;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.support.ServletUriComponentsBuilder;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class FileController {
    private FileService files;
    public FileController(FileService files) {
        this.files = files;
    }
    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public FileUpload uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
        String fileName = files.storeFile(file);
        String fileUri = ServletUriComponentsBuilder.fromCurrentContextPath().path("/downloadFile/").path(fileName).toUriString();
        return new FileUpload(fileName, fileUri, file.getContentType(), file.getSize());
    }
    @PostMapping("/uploadFile")
    public List<FileUpload> uploadFile_(@RequestParam("files") MultipartFile[] files){
        return Arrays.asList(files).stream().map(file->uploadFile(file)).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
    @GetMapping("/downloadFile/{fileName:.+}")
    public ResponseEntity<Resource> downloadFile(@PathVariable String fileName, 
            HttpServletRequest request){
        Resource resource = files.loadFileAsResource(fileName);
        String contentType = null;
        try {
            contentType = request.getServletContext().getMimeType(resource.getFile().getAbsolutePath());
        }catch(IOException ioe) {
        }
        if(contentType == null) {
            contentType = "application/octet-stream";
        }
        return ResponseEntity.ok().contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(contentType)).header(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=\"" + resource.getFilename() + "\"").body(resource);    
    }
}
```

FileService.java
File upload support

```
import com.spring.file.exception.FileNotFoundException;
import com.spring.file.exception.FileStorageException;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;
import org.springframework.core.io.UrlResource;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.util.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;
 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardCopyOption;
 
@Service
@Slf4j
public class FileService {
    private final Environment env;
    private final Path fileLocation;
    @Autowired
    public FileService(Environment env) {
        this.env = env;
        this.fileLocation = Paths.get(env.getProperty("file.uploadDir")).toAbsolutePath().normalize();
        try {
            Files.createDirectories(this.fileLocation);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new FileStorageException("", ex);
        }
    }
    
    public String storeFile(MultipartFile file) {
        String fileName = StringUtils.cleanPath(file.getOriginalFilename());
        try {
            if(fileName.contains("..")) {
                throw new FileStorageException("Sorry! Filename contains invalid path sequence " + fileName);
            }
            Path targetLocation = this.fileLocation.resolve(fileName);
            Files.copy(file.getInputStream(), targetLocation, StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
            return fileName;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            throw new FileStorageException("Could not store file " + fileName + ". Please try again!", ex);
        }
    }
    public Resource loadFileAsResource(String fileName) {
        try {
            Path filePath = this.fileLocation.resolve(fileName).normalize();
            Resource resource = new UrlResource(filePath.toUri());
            if(resource.exists()) {
                return resource;
            } else {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found " + fileName);
            }
        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("File not found " + fileName, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

FileUpload.java
File upload on site

```
public class FileUpload {
    private String fileName;
    private String fileDownloadUri;
    private String fileType;
    private long size;
 
    public FileUpload(String fileName, String fileDownloadUri, String fileType, long size) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileDownloadUri = fileDownloadUri;
        this.fileType = fileType;
        this.size = size;
    }
 
    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }
 
    public void setFileName(String fileName) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
    }
 
    public String getFileDownloadUri() {
        return fileDownloadUri;
    }
 
    public void setFileDownloadUri(String fileDownloadUri) {
        this.fileDownloadUri = fileDownloadUri;
    }
 
    public String getFileType() {
        return fileType;
    }
 
    public void setFileType(String fileType) {
        this.fileType = fileType;
    }
 
    public long getSize() {
        return size;
    }
 
    public void setSize(long size) {
        this.size = size;
    }
}
```

I'm not sure what exactly is causing the error.

Comment: Have you set the value of `file.uploadDir` env property?

Comment: In the past, you didn't have to set any properties to do just fine. Maybe we should make an exception for this?

Comment: If the `env.getProperty("file.uploadDir")` returns `null` the `FileService` constructor will be failed, this will create a chain reaction that causes the spring bean creation to be failed.

Comment: Should I then add processing without allowing nulls?